# Does Redux have a nicer way to handle a very large state object?

Tags: redux

We're planning an Electron app, and we're considering Redux. The app is going to have a *huge* state, data potentially being read from dozens or hundreds of files. While doing some research to understand Redux, I found that the reducer method must never alter the state, and must create a new state with any changes. This is going to be a problem if the state of the app is very large, since now we need to deeply copy everything in the state (it's going to be a bunch of nested objects), and we're going to take up double the memory that was being used to hold the state once, then the old state will be deleted. This doesn't seem ideal at all.

Is there a better way to handle this in situation in Redux?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't deeply copy. In fact, I'd say deep-copying is counter-intuitive to the redux-way.

You'll be copying by **reference** most of the time, which is very fast.

If you're worried about your state tree being too large, I recommend [redux-ignore](https://github.com/omnidan/redux-ignore), to break things down.

I'm currently running a redux app that has over 200 reducers. I've yet to detect a bottleneck due to redux, even on cheap android mobile devices.

Comment: But the author (on egghead.io) said that the state needs to be completely immutable. He even went out of his way to make sure the reducer doesn't touch anything in the original state ([video of that](https://egghead.io/lessons/javascript-redux-avoiding-object-mutations-with-object-assign-and-spread)).

Comment: Yes, that's why using immutable data structures helps a lot. You'll be using `Object.assign` and `Array.slice` a lot to achieve that. You should look into [relational-json](https://github.com/SebastienDaniel/relational-json) and [immutable](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) to help you at that level.

Comment: Right, but what if that's not feasible for a really large amount of data?

Comment: Yeah, you're definitely over-thinking that comment.  Shallow copies, which are what you need, just copy around pointers and references, not all the data.  Also see the Redux FAQ on this topic, at http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#performance-clone-state .

Comment: Also, if you've got nested data, the Redux recommendation is to normalize it and flatten it as much as possible.  See http://redux.js.org/docs/FAQ.html#organizing-state-nested-data .

Comment: @Hassan I built relational-json (see previous comment) specifically for large redux stores.
It flattens your data and makes it immutable. I've tested it on large data-sets  and haven't had any perf issues, even on mobile. I'd be more than happy to help you get started with the lib, if you need guidance.

Comment: I appreciate it. I will certainly ask if I run into issues. Thanks again for your help.